# Code first migration executed in application code

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I would like to exeucte my classes (that extend from DbMigration) when the application is starting.

Currently I have the following code in the startup:

Database.SetInitializer(
                new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion());
Database.Initialize(false);

This is working fine and calls my configuration which is creating a connection to the database. The only thing is that I don't know is how my DbMigration classes are executed so that the database changes are executed on the server.

This code is executed without any problems:

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CustomerDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()

         {
            PgSqlConnectionInfo connectionInfo =
                PgSqlConnectionInfo.CreateConnection(
                    "User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=etera;Schema=dev;");
            TargetDatabase = connectionInfo;
            SetSqlGenerator(connectionInfo.GetInvariantName(), new PgSqlEntityMigrationSqlGenerator());
        }

    }
```

It does not execute the following code - which should create the table:

```
public class CreateBlogTable : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "Blogs",
                c => new
                         {
                             BlogId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                             Name = c.String(unicode: false),
                         })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.BlogId);
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("Blogs");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you use Add-Migration command to create a new migration or did you just created a class?

Comment: I just created the class. Which additional steps does the command execute that I miss when creating it manually?

Comment: It creates additional autogenerated file with serialized model. The answer to your question is: use Add-Migration.

Comment: Sounds like the solution. If you add it as an answer I would accept it.